# Regexp with a maximum of 2 consecutive equal chars and other options

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm totally new with regualr expressions and I have to build one with the following requisites:

- between 8 and 15 chars
- at least 1 alphabetic char (a-z,A-Z)
- at least 1 non alphabetic (all the others)
- at least 1 CAPITAL letter
- at least 1 non-capital letter
- maximum of 2 consecutive equal chars (e.g.: 'g' accepted, 'gg' accepted, 'ggg' not)

I tried with this one, but it works only with a maximum of 5 consecutive equal chars (dont understand why). What I'm doing wrong?

```
var regexp = /^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(.{8,15})(?!.*(.)\1{2}))$/;
```

EDIT it works with

```
asdfghjkl1Q
asdfghjkl1QQQ
asdfghjkl1QQQQQ
```

it not works with

```
asdfghjkl1QQQQQQ
asdfghjkl1QQQQQq
```

what i'm trying to obtain is:
WORKING with :

```
asdfghjkl1Q
asdfghjkl1QQ
asdfghjkl11
```

NOT WORKING with:

```
asdfghjkl1QQQ
asdfghjkl1QQq
asdfghjkl111
```

Comment: Looks like password validation. You may benefit from [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/)

Comment: It will help everyone to help you more effectively if you post a few lines of your test data

Comment: Put your negative lookahead before the `(.{8,15})` portion. Remove `{2}` and remove the `()` around the whole expression or change `\1` to `\2`

Comment: thanks for the link, it seems very interesting...unfortunately, i have to do that way;
I tried putting the `(?!.*(.)\1{2})` before the `(.{8,15})` but it does not work at all, neither the previous rules

Comment: @GreatBigBore it's pretty simple:
`if (regexp.test(password)) {
                console.log("ok!");
            }
            else {
                console.log("no...");
            }`

Comment: @Diego I mean the data that you're trying to match.

Comment: @GreatBigBore is suggesting sample data which you assert should pass.

Comment: Following @ctwheels advice leads to `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?!.*(.)\1{2})(.{8,15})$/`, and that does matches as desired. Note that one of your 'working' examples shoudn't work, as it doesn't contain an uppercase letter....

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual regex and the actual test data you're using? I ask because when I run what you posted, and change this `asdfghjkl11` to `asdfghjkl11Q` (per your capital letter requirement), the "WORKING" section works perfectly, just as you have specified.

Comment: And have you studied the link that @ctwheels posted?

Comment: @Diego Question though, why should `asdfghjkl11` match? This does not contain a capital letter and why should `asdfghjkl1QQq` not match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need the outer capturing group so you might omit it.

You could first check for the 8,15 characters until the end of the string `$` using a lookahead `(?=.{8,15}$)`

If all the lookaheads match, then match any character one or more times `.+`

Try it like this:

[`^(?=.{8,15}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?!.*(.)\1{2}).+$`](https://regex101.com/r/aLJ0L2/2)